# NativeScript app router error. my app dont start

Tags: nativescript, router-outlet

i'm getting an error while i'm running my app.

my app build like this :
the app-component should navigate to the app-routes and from there to the pages-component .
the pages-component template is 'router-outlet' and it navigates to the pages-routes that is navigate between the views.

i did it like this :

Main app-component :

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { PagesComponent } from '~/pages/pages.component'

@Component({
    selector: "ns-app",
    template: "<router-outlet></router-outlet>"
})

export class AppComponent { }
```

Main app-routes :

```
import { PagesComponent } from "~/pages/pages.component";
import { LoginComponent } from "~/pages/login/login.component";
import { RegisterComponent } from "~/pages/register/register.component";
import { AuthGuard } from "~/@shared/services/auth-guard.service";
import { TaskListComponent } from "~/pages/task-list/task-list.component";


export const AUTH_PROVIDERS = [
    AuthGuard
]; 
export const APP_ROUTES = [

    { path: "", redirectTo: "/pages", pathMatch: "full" },
    { path: "**", redirectTo: "" },

    ];
```

pages-component :

```
import { OnInit, Component } from "@angular/core";
import { RouterExtensions } from "nativescript-angular/router";
import { Router } from "@angular/router";

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: "pages",
    template: "<router-outlet></router-outlet>"
})
export class PagesComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private routerExtensions: RouterExtensions, private router: 
Router) {

    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
    }


}
```

pages-routes :

```
import { NativeScriptRouterModule } from "nativescript-angular/router";
import { ModuleWithProviders } from "@angular/core";
import { PagesComponent } from "~/pages/pages.component";
import { LoginComponent } from "~/pages/login/login.component";
import { RegisterComponent } from "~/pages/register/register.component";
import { AuthGuard } from "~/@shared/services/auth-guard.service";
import { TaskListComponent } from "~/pages/task-list/task-list.component";



const PAGES_ROUTES = [
            {path: "pages", component: PagesComponent, children: [
            { path: "login", component: LoginComponent },
            { path: "register", component: RegisterComponent },
            { path: "task-list", canActivate: [AuthGuard], component: 
TaskListComponent },
            { path: "", redirectTo: "/task-list", pathMatch: "full" },

        ]
    },

];
//, canActivate:[AuthGuard]
export const PagesRoutingModule: ModuleWithProviders = 
NativeScriptRouterModule.forRoot(PAGES_ROUTES);
```

the error I've got :

[The Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HyPim.jpg)

what do you think can be the problem ? am i missing something?

thank you !

Comment: Ensure that you have imported NativeScriptRouterModule in root module.

imports: [ NativeScriptRouterModule,NativeScriptRouterModule.forRoot(routes)   ]

Comment: yes iv'e imported the NativeScriptRouterModule

Comment: Could you please create https://play.nativescript.org/ sample

Comment: what do you mean to create sample ? sorry for the question.

Comment: goto to play.nativescript.org and copy your code over there so as to reproduce the problem. Then paste the link here so i can take a look at the code. It work just like plunker/Jsfiddle etc.